# Disable Linux vsyscall vdso vvar

Tags: linux, security, memory

I am implementing a Linux security sandbox for a custom bytecode interpreter through seccomp mode. To minimize as much as possible the attack surface, I want to run it in a completely clean virtual address space. I only need code and data segments plus stack available, but I do not need vsyscall, vdso nor vvar.

Is there any way to disable allocation of this pages for a given process?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, you will have to disable vsyscall/vDSO globally if you want the mapping itself to be unavailable. If you only want the program to be unable to call vsyscall/vDSO syscalls, then seccomp will be able to do it. Some caveats though:

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt

> On x86-64, vsyscall emulation is enabled by default.  (vsyscalls are
>   legacy variants on vDSO calls.)  Currently, emulated vsyscalls will honor seccomp, with a few oddities:
>
> - A return value of SECCOMP_RET_TRAP will set a si_call_addr pointing to
>     the vsyscall entry for the given call and not the address after the
>     'syscall' instruction.  Any code which wants to restart the call
>     should be aware that (a) a ret instruction has been emulated and (b)
>     trying to resume the syscall will again trigger the standard vsyscall
>     emulation security checks, making resuming the syscall mostly
>     pointless.
> - A return value of SECCOMP_RET_TRACE will signal the tracer as usual,
>     but the syscall may not be changed to another system call using the
>     orig_rax register. It may only be changed to -1 order to skip the
>     currently emulated call. Any other change MAY terminate the process.
>     The rip value seen by the tracer will be the syscall entry address;
>     this is different from normal behavior.  The tracer MUST NOT modify
>     rip or rsp.  (Do not rely on other changes terminating the process.
>     They might work.  For example, on some kernels, choosing a syscall
>     that only exists in future kernels will be correctly emulated (by
>     returning -ENOSYS).
>
> To detect this quirky behavior, check for addr & ~0x0C00 ==
>   0xFFFFFFFFFF600000.  (For SECCOMP_RET_TRACE, use rip.  For
>   SECCOMP_RET_TRAP, use siginfo->si_call_addr.)  Do not check any other
>   condition: future kernels may improve vsyscall emulation and current
>   kernels in vsyscall=native mode will behave differently, but the
>   instructions at 0xF...F600{0,4,8,C}00 will not be system calls in these
>   cases.
>
> Note that modern systems are unlikely to use vsyscalls at all -- they
>   are a legacy feature and they are considerably slower than standard
>   syscalls.  New code will use the vDSO, and vDSO-issued system calls
>   are indistinguishable from normal system calls.

So emulated vsyscalls can be confined by seccomp, and vDSOs are likewise confined by seccomp. If you disable `gettimeofday()`, the confined program will not be able to call that syscall through emulated vsyscall, vDSO, or regular syscall. If you confine them this way with seccomp, you shouldn't have to worry about the attack surface they create.

If you are worried about an attacker exploiting the vDSO mapping itself (which doesn't require calling a syscall), then I don't believe there's a way to disable it on a per-process basis reliably. You can prevent it from being linked in, but it would be hard to prevent a compromised bytecode interpreter from allocating memory and putting it back. You can boot with the `vdso=0` kernel parameter which will disable it globally, though, so linking it in would do nothing.